# How to change font size of drl (drool) file in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, fonts, drools

How to change font size of drl (drool) file in Eclipse?

[image: Eclipse view of Preferences to choose Colors and Fonts]

I dont see any file type with Jboss/Drool or drl text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a direct way to do this just for .drl files (even with the drools plugin installed).

By default eclipse will use the general text editor for drools files. 
You can change the font size for this in `Preferences/General/Appearance/colors and Fonts... Basic/Text Font`
...this will affect all text files, not just .drl's.